# Pass generic parameter as agrument

Tags: scala, akka

What I want to do is (currently does not compile):

```
def createSystem(system:ActorSystem, actorMap: Map[String, type]) = {
    for( (name, actor) <- actorMap){
      system.actorOf(Props[type], name) //<- should be called like Props[MyActor1]   
    }
  }
```

and then call it like:

```
def standardSystem(system:ActorSystem):Unit = {
    createSystem(
      system,
    Map(
      "actor1" -> classOf[MyActor1],
      "actor2" -> classOf[MyActor2]
    ))
  }
```

The problem is that Props[T] expects type to be passed in, but I don't know how to pass type in the map, and how to refer to this type in the call to Props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akka's `Props` provides an [`create`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.4/#akka.actor.Props) method that takes a class.  Just call it with your class:

```
system.actorOf(Props.create(actor), name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the map  `Map[String , Class[_ <: Actor]]`

As was answered above use Props.create(actor) and iterate it

```
for ( (name,clazz) <- actorMap ) {
  system.actorOf(Props.create(clazz) , name )
}
```